# Oracle Apex - Update Table 1, based on another Table 2, if column string in Table 1 does not already exist in Table 1

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a table `ORDERS` in which contains order data and customer data.

[image]

[image]

I also have another table `CUSTOMERS`. Essentially, I want to:

- Update table `CUSTOMERS` with the data from table `ORDERS` with the data that is currently in the table. I'll have a separate question on how to do this 'on insert and update'.
- `CUSTOMERS` table should check if the `EMAIL` column string already exists in the table.
- If the `EMAIL` matches and exists, then should not insert a new row. However, `CUSTOMERS` table contains a column `NUMBER_OF_ORDERS` (which is a number datatype with a default of 1) and should add +1 to that column. (ex: `NUMBER_OF_ORDERS`**:2**)
- If not, then `CUSTOMERS` table should insert a new row with `ORDERS` table columns (`FIRST_NAME`, `LAST_NAME`, `EMAIL`, `NUMBER_OF_ORDERS`**:1**, etc..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally take a different approach.

- Create customer records as you describe
- Create a view to display the count of orders for a customer instead of storing that number in a column.

1. Creating the customer record. For this you could use the [merge](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement) statement. You could do this as part of the trigger you described in earlier questions.

```
create table customers (
    id                             number generated by default on null as identity 
                                   constraint customers_pk primary key,
    email                           varchar2(100 char),
    first_name                      varchar2(100 char)
)
;

Table CUSTOMERS created.

insert into customers (email, first_name) VALUES ('john@test.com', 'John');

1 row inserted.

merge into customers c
      using (
        select 'john@test.com' as email,
               'John' as first_name
          from dual
            ) t
      on (t.email = c.email)
  when not matched then
    insert (email, first_name)
    values (t.email, t.first_name);

0 rows merged. >> row for this email already exists so it isn't inserted

merge into customers c
      using (
        select 'bill@test.com' as email,
               'Bill' as first_name
          from dual
            ) t
      on (t.email = c.email)
  when not matched then
    insert (email, first_name)
    values (t.email, t.first_name);

1 row merged.
```

2. Create a view to hold the orders count for a customer.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE view CUSTOMER_ORDERS (email, order_count) AS
SELECT c.email, COUNT(o.order_number)
  FROM customers c LEFT OUTER JOIN orders o on c.email = o.email
  GROUP BY c.email;
```

Using a view has the advantage that you don't need to maintain it - it will always return the current data.

Comment: Koen, you're a legend. I did read about using `merge` for this but I wasn't exactly sure how to go about doing this. Now I know. Thank you so much. I do have a follow up question on implementing this with the current trigger that I have. Your help is sincerely appreciated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75571326/oracle-apex-22-21-rest-data-source-multiple-table-inserts-on-one-trigger