# Oracle Apex 22.21 - REST data source - multiple table inserts on one trigger

Tags: oracle-apex

This question is a follow up to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75559649/oracle-apex-update-table-1-based-on-another-table-2-if-column-string-in-tabl/75560875#75560875).

I have an app with a REST Data Source taking in JSON responses from an API. There are two tables **ORDERS** and **LINES**. The **ORDERS** table contains a column **LINES** which is a JSON Document type.

I created a trigger on my **ORDERS** table which runs `AFTER INSERT or UPDATE` on my **ORDERS** table, and which maintains the **LINES** table (Extracts the JSON array from the **ORDERS** table **ORDER_ITEMS** column and inserts into **ORDER_ITEMS** table and each column).

```
create or replace trigger "TR_MAINTAIN_LINES"
AFTER
insert or update on "ORDERS"
for each row
begin
    if inserting or updating then
        if updating then
          delete LINES
          where order_number = :old.order_number;
        end if;
        insert into LINES ( order_number, product, quantity, price, total_price, item_image) 
        ( select :new.order_number,
                 j.product,
                 j.quantity,
                 j.price,
                 TO_NUMBER(j.price,'$999.99'),
                 j.item_image
            from json_table( 
                     :new.lines,
                     '$[*]' columns (
                         product  varchar2(4000) path '$.product',
                         quantity number        path '$.quantity',
                         price    varchar2(4000) path '$.price', 
                         item_image varchar2(4000) path '$.item_image' ) ) j );
    end if;
end;
```

I also have another table **CUSTOMERS**. This table is to contain customer data such as **FIRST_NAME**, **LAST_NAME**, and **EMAIL**.

I have merged the existing data from the **ORDERS** table to the **CUSTOMERS** table with the following:

```
merge into customers c
      using (
        select 
               first_name,
               last_name,
               email
          from orders
            ) o
      on (o.email = c.email)
  when not matched then
    insert (first_name, last_name, email)
    values (o.first_name, o.last_name, o.email);
```

Now, I want to create a trigger so that the customer data inserts into **CUSTOMERS** table on a trigger (after insert or update on the **ORDERS** table). Is this possible within the trigger **TR_MAINTAIN_LINES** above or would I have to create a separate trigger?

```
SAMPLE JSON RESPONSE FROM API
[ {
  "order_number": "so1223",
  "order_date": "2022-07-01",
  "first_name": "Carny",
  "last_name": "Coulter",
  "email": "ccoulter2@ovh.net",
  "credit_card": "3545556133694494",
  "city": "Myhiya",
  "state": "CA",
  "zip_code": "12345",
  "lines": [
    {
      "product": "Beans - Fava, Canned",
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": $1.99
    },
    {
      "product": "Edible Flower - Mixed",
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": $1.50
    }
  ]
},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to just add it to the same trigger. Since you can't select from the orders table yet, use a select from dual. Like this:

```
merge into customers c
      using (
        select 
               :new.first_name,
               :new.last_name,
               :new.email
          from dual
            ) o
      on (o.email = c.email)
  when not matched then
    insert (first_name, last_name, email)
    values (o.first_name, o.last_name, o.email);
```

On a side note, there is some redundant code in the trigger:

```
...
AFTER
--line below ensures the trigger only fires 
-- on an insert or update operation
insert or update on "ORDERS"
for each row
begin
--if statement below will always yield true. 
-- since trigger has "after insert or update"
-- It can be removed 
    if inserting or updating then
        if updating then
...
```